# how do I iterate an excel formula down multiple rows using python

Tags: python, excel, loops, for-loop

I an very new to Python ,have no real coding knowledge and am stuck. I have an excel spreadsheet. The first column heading is Land Data. Land data has either Allotment or Farm listed underneath it. I have a second column with the heading Outcome with the formula =IF(A2="Farm","Yes","No").

My code below just does the calculation for the first row.
How do I iterate this formula down many rows  of the Outcome column using Python.

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
ws1=wb.active
ws1["C2"]= '=IF(A2="farm","Yes","No")'
wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the number of rows you want to change you could do something like:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
ws1 = wb.active

last_row = 10  # For example

for i in range(2, last_row):
    cell = "C" + str(i)
    a_cell = "A" + str(i)
    ws1[cell] = '=IF(' + a_cell + '="farm","Yes","No")'
wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

You basically iterate over each one of the rows and create the formula for each one of those.

Also, you could improve/automatice that if you can somehow get the quantity of rows your sheet has, and assign that to the `last_row` variable, instead of hardcoding it like I did in the example.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you Lucas! Much appreciated.

Comment: You are welcome!. Please mark the answer as the correct one if that solved your question.